# Get Value of a hidden form_input using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot get the hidden value of form if it is hidden.

My form view:

```
<?php echo form_input(array(
        'class'=>'emp_name',
        'name'=>'emp_name',
        'id'=>'emp_name',
        'value'=>'')
    );?>


<?php echo form_hidden('emp_id', ''); ?>
```

I set employee name by using jquery autocomplete and then set the emp_id value to the returned ID with the name.

My Controller:

```
$data = array(
            'emp_id'=>$this->input->post('emp_id')
    );
```

This conroller is the form of my view above. I can get the emp_name properly but not the emp_id because it is hidden, if I do not use hidden it works fine. Any idea how can I hide the ID by getting the value in my conntroler?

Comment: I have no trouble with getting hidden input value by $this->input->post(). Can You check whether or not proper value is send to controller by for example var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: I guess you shouldn't send ''. That's probably why you're not getting anything back. try something like true or 1.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you are not submitting the form to the system.

You need to open/close and submit the form.

Quick little test:

```php
class Test_form extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //displays the profiler info to make debugging easy
        $this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
    }

    function test_form()
    {
        echo form_open();
        echo form_input(array(
            'class'=>'emp_name',
            'name'=>'emp_name',
            'id'=>'emp_name',
            'value'=>'')
            );
        echo form_hidden('emp_id', '');
        echo form_submit();
        echo form_close();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i just showed you the impt. parts. ofcourse i opened and closed the form.